# Problem Sending data send to a block

Tags: forms

after form submit in a page its return some value,I want to prnt this value in a block .how can I do this?
and I want the form and the block are in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Use [hook_block_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7) and [hook_block_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7). Something like this:

```
function MYMODULE_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();

  switch ($delta) {
    case 'my_block':

      $blockContent = '<p>Nothing to show</p>';

      // assuming we're getting it from POST but the source can be whatever you want
      if (isset($_POST['key']) && null != $_POST['key']) {
          $blockContent = '<p>' . $_POST['key'] . '</p>';
      }

      $block['subject'] = t('My Block Title');
      $block['content'] = array(
          '#markup' => $blockContent
      );
      break;
  }

  return $block;
}
```